# Get how many (if any) objects of a class are contained in a list

Tags: list, python-2.7, class

Hi all this might seem like a useless question since I found a way of doing it but I would like to know if there is a faster way to get the number of items of a list which verify a certain class.

So far I am doing:

```
items_from_class = 0
for x in Mylist:
    if isinstance(x, Myclass):
        items_from_class += 1
if items_from_class > 2;
    do something ...
```

I would like something that fits in one line, like:

```
if isinstance(x,Myclass) in Mylist > 2:
    do something ...
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Yes, break if you find three.there is no point checking any more if all you want is to know if there are three or more

Comment: Yes, at the moment that's all I need but I was asking the question for more general purposes as I will have other uses for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprising that people want to create lists, or lambdas, for no reason.

```
if sum(1 for x in items if isinstance(x, MyClass)) > 2:
    ## do stuff
```

Answer (score -1):

You can you the following code for your requirement

```
myClassElements = [ x for x in itemList if isinstance(x,MyClass) ]
if len(myClassElements) > 2:
   ...do something
```

Hope that answers your question

Comment: The down-vote is because it is inefficient is it? The reason i posted this was the interpreter can do the optimization and the code is more readable. Also the code is in one line as is the requirement.

Comment: What do you mean by inefficient ? Would I be better off sticking to my formulation using a 'break' as suggested by @Padraic Cunningham ? I am developing a 2D game in Pygame so I think it should be fine to use your suggestion as the game is unlikely to be very demanding overall.

Comment: (my) downvote is because it's just sloppy code - creating an entire list, just to take the length of the list, when you're not going to use the list again. Sure, it works, but so does the Original Post; the point is to write *better* code, and that includes more Pythonic.